# Adding a Login method in fixture.before hook is giving an error in Testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcafe, ui-testing

**Agenda**: I wanted to run login method before all tests and Logout method after all tests, so that if the before hook fails, the test execution won't happen.

I added login logic in fixture.before hook as shown in the code below. But it's giving the following error, can some help me to fix it.

[image]

**Test file**

```
import { Selector } from "testcafe";
import LoginPage from '../page-objects/login.po';

const loginPage = new LoginPage();

fixture`Getting Started`
.page`https://example.com/`
.before(async t => {
    await loginPage.login();
});

test("My First Test", async t => {
    const str = await Selector('.home-container h1').textContent;
    console.log(str);
});
```

**Pageobjects class**

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';
import CommonFunctions from '../commons/common-fns'

export default class LoginPage{


    constructor () {                 
        this.emailTxtBox = Selector('input[type="email"]');
        this.nextBttn = Selector('button[type="submit"]');
        this.microsoftNextBttn = Selector('input[type="submit"]');
        this.passwordTxtBox = Selector('input[type="password"]');
        this.signinBttn = Selector('input[type="submit"]');
        this.noBttn = Selector('#idBtn_Back');
    }

     async login() {
        await t
        .typeText(this.emailTxtBox, '')
        .click(this.nextBttn)
        .typeText(this.emailTxtBox, '')
        .click(this.microsoftNextBttn)
        .typeText(this.passwordTxtBox, '')
        .click(this.signinBttn)
        .click(this.noBttn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `beforeEach` fixture hook instead of `before`
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#fixture-hooks

Comment: But `beforeEach` will run the logic before each test in the suite. i want the login logic to be run before the first test, not before each test.

Comment: Before fixture hooks are executed between test runs and do not have access to the tested page. And every test starts in a new session, so it might automatically log you out.